# i installed 5.1.6-1 dse cassandra after sometime 6.7 version getting installed by it's own

Tags: shell, cassandra

## Package                                             Arch                                 Version                                  Repository                               Size

Removing:
 datastax-agent                                      noarch                               6.7.6-1                                  @DataStax                                74 M
 dse                                                 noarch                               5.1.6-1                                  @DataStax                               170 M
 dse                                                 noarch                               6.7.7-1                                  installed                               288 M
 dse-full                                            noarch                               5.1.6-1                                  @DataStax                               489 k
 dse-full                                            noarch                               6.7.7-1                                  installed                               561 k
 dse-libcassandra                                    noarch                               5.1.6-1                                  @DataStax                                58 M
 dse-libcassandra                                    noarch                               6.7.7-1                                  installed                                63 M
 dse-libgraph                                        noarch                               5.1.6-1                                  @DataStax                                27 M
 dse-libgraph                                        noarch                               6.7.7-1                                  installed                               129 M
 dse-libhadoop2-client                               noarch                               5.1.6-1                                  @DataStax                                63 M
 dse-libhadoop2-client                               noarch                               6.7.7-1                                  installed                                72 M
 dse-liblog4j                                        noarch                               5.1.6-1                                  @DataStax                                13 k
 dse-liblog4j                                        noarch                               6.7.7-1                                  installed                                13 k
 dse-libsolr                                         noarch                               5.1.6-1                                  @DataStax                                83 M
 dse-libsolr                                         noarch                               6.7.7-1                                  installed                                78 M
 dse-libspark                                        noarch                               5.1.6-1                                  @DataStax                               432 M
 dse-libspark                                        noarch                               6.7.7-1                                  installed                               432 M
 dse-libtomcat                                       noarch                               5.1.6-1                                  @DataStax                               8.0 M
 dse-libtomcat                                       noarch                               6.7.7-1                                  installed                               5.8 M

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to figure out why 6.7 was installed, and as you mentioned, "on its own"? If so, that's a pretty hard question to answer, but you could go look at the yum history to see who did it and when. One guess is that you have the Datastax repo as part of your system repo lists, and it's possible that someone tried to patch the system with something similar to "yum update" (without specifying what to update), and the Datastax RPMs were updated with that command. I say that because it accidentally happened where I work. Since then we don't have the Datastax Repo as part of our system repositories any more (we could simply disable it, but we didn't want to leave it to chance that someone may re-enable it by accident). Otherwise, if that's not your question, you'll have to be a bit more specific.

Comment: yum history
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-----------------------------------------------
    25 | root <root>              | 2020-02-21 05:56 | I, U           |   18 **
    24 | <pushpa_kumari | 2020-02-20 06:19 | Install        |    1 EE
    23 | <pushpa_kumari | 2020-02-20 06:19 | Install        |    9
    22 | <pushpa_kumari | 2020-02-20 06:17 | Erase          |   19 EE

Comment: 21 | root <root>              | 2020-02-20 05:36 | I, U           |   10 **
    20 | root <root>              | 2020-02-19 16:34 | I, U           |   62 **
    19 | System <unset>           | 2020-02-19 12:47 | Install        |    3 EE
    18 | System <unset>           | 2020-02-19 12:47 | Install        |    9
    17 | System <unset>           | 2020-02-19 12:47 | Install        |    1
    16 | System <unset>           | 2020-02-19 12:47 | Update         |    2 EE

Comment: 15 | System <unset>           | 2020-02-19 12:47 | Install        |    2
    14 | System <unset>           | 2020-02-19 12:46 | Install        |    1 EE
    13 | System <unset>           | 2020-02-19 12:45 | Install        |    2
    12 |  <ansible>               | 2019-12-13 12:00 | Install        |    5 E<
    11 |  <ansible>               | 2019-12-13 11:57 | Install        |    1 >E
    10 |  <ansible>               | 2019-12-13 11:57 | Install        |   65

Comment: update is getting triggered along with install. why this is happening i am using below install command. Yes, Repository is having both the versions 5.1.6 and 6.6.7

Comment: sudo yum install -y dse-full-5.1.6-1;

Comment: #Add the Datastax Yum repository
echo "[DataStax]
name=Datastax Repo for Datastax Enterprise
baseurl=http://******artifactory/datastax/enterprise/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/yum.repos.d/datastax.repo;